# Is there a way to skip some routes by react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on a project with create-react-app and i am planning to use strapi as my admin. I am using "react-router-dom" package for handling all my routes. However, i want to skip "/admin" from 'react-router-dom' and let it make a request to server to access strapi admin. For instance, this is how my project is handling routes at the moment.

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
   <Route exact path='/article' component={Article}/>
   <Route exact path='/article/:id' component={ArticleDetail}/>
   <Route component={NoMatchRoute}/>
   <Route exact path='/admin' render={() => //redirect to www.example.com/admin}/>
 </Switch>
```

In above example when i try to go to /admin route, it is giving me No page found and it just goes in loop, however...if i hard reload my browser, i am being able to go to the strapi admin login page, which is kind of annoying for everyday use. Any helpful tips will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try this: ```() => window.location = 'www.example.com/admin'}``` in the render function?

Answer (score 0):

> You can skip some routes by specifing `<Redirect/>`

```
<Switch>
       <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
       <Route exact path='/article' component={Article}/>
       <Route exact path='/article/:id' component={ArticleDetail}/>
       <Redirect exact path='/admin' to="www.example.com/admin"/> // use "https://www.example.com/admin" if it doesn't work
       <Route component={NoMatchRoute}/>
</Switch>
```